# If $X$ has finitely many connected components then any connected component is open. Which subset in $X$ are open and closed?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am currently reading Topology and for guidance I'm following my college lectures and the book by Munkres. I'm still in the beginning so I'm having a difficulty to understand the following :

> If $X$ has finitely many connected components then any connected component is open. Which subset in $X$ are open and closed?

Firstly, I know that a component is closed so in this case each component can be expressed as the complement of the union of other components (i.e. closed sets) and hence each component becomes open.

Is there any role of the "connected" part here? I can't seem to find it.

Also my second question is what is meant by *Which subset in $X$ are open and closed?*. Is it saying that I need to find which subsets are clopen or closed/open?

Can I get some help please?

Comment: @Arthur Thank you. Also can you tell me that if the "connected" part has anything to do with proving that each component is open?

Comment: A point to bear in mind: $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself are always both open and closed. (And as an aside, you might like to think about $\{0\} \cup \{1/n \mid n \in \Bbb{N}_{>0}\} \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, for an example where the connected components are not all clopen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are asked to find all the clopen subsets of a topological space with finitely many (connected) components.

The term "connected component" is basically interchangeable with "component" in this context. It is called "connected" because it is a maximal connected subspace. They are called "connected components" not because they are components that happen to be connected, but because they are components with respect to connectivity. (At least, that's how I always thought about it.)

There are, technically, other ways to decompose a topological space, so maybe the author wanted to be precise. Or maybe they, like me, call those things "connected components" out of habit without much more thought.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: I've found that a subset is clopen iff it is a union of components. I've proved the part that if it's the union of components then it is clopen. But how do I prove that if it is clopen then it is a union of components?

Comment: @Itachi For each point in some clopen set $A$, consider the component that contains it. Prove that that component lies inside $A$. Now take the union of all of those components.

Comment: Yes I did it thay way. Thank you for the comments.